# Ubuntu 22.04 - Cloned SSD boot drive, now system is ONLY booting from clones

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I'm running into a bit of an issue trying to configure a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine (using an HP Microserver Gen10 Plus, to be exact).

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I've been tasked to create a bootable clone of this machine's main SSD drive. The idea is to then update files on this bootable clone from the main SSD as time goes on, via rsync or something. Haven't gotten that far yet. Should the SSD ever fail, the machine should be able to boot from the clone drive, and all important files should be up to date.

**What I have done so far:**

So far, I used Clonezilla to create a bootable clone of the main SSD to two mechanical hard drives, first drive sda, then drive sdb.

**The Problem & What I've tried:**

The problem I'm running into now is that no matter what I do, the machine only boots to cloned drive sdb. If I unplug that, it boots to drive sdba and only if I unplug both mechanical drives does it properly boot into the SSD.

I have tried removing boot options in the HP Microserver's BIOS. I have tried updating the grub on all three drives. Even when the grub screen appears and I hard-select to boot from the nvmen01 drive, the system -still- boots from cloned drive sdb or sda.

Anyone got any idea on where this issue could be?

Do note that this is one of my first forays into setting up a Ubuntu system from scratch, so I may not be 100% up to date with how things work exactly.

Comment: If you clone the whole drive (ie. *have more than one drive/partition with the same UUIDs*) then what will boot is *undefined* as that is a situation that is supposed to not occur. This means the results for one machine will differ to others. Have you handled the UUIDs and ensured they are UUID's - ie. Unique!

Comment: I figured it would be something as simple as that.
I ended up fixing things by booting off of a live USB, then I generated new UUIDs for both mechanical hard drives in the system and updated the grub. After that, boot started behaving normally again.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!